# Changing the property of toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, wpftoolkit

How do I change the windows phone toolkit property of an object (for example a `Stack Panel`) in C#.

The particular property is referred to as toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled (of type bool) in .xaml, but I don't know how to access it in C#.

Thanks, I hope someone can shed some light on the matter.

Comment: [You should read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TiltEffect.SetIsTiltEnabled(MyStackPanel, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have this effect on all elememts of the grid then in your xaml page 
define like `toolkit:IsTiltEffect.Isenabled = true` and if you want any specific control to follow this property then ..   `Tilteffect.Settiltenabled(control,true);` in .cs file

i hope this will help